# Symfony Doctrine Change Date format of Entity datetime field

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

so I have an Entity with a Datetimetz field, with it default format is `Y-m-d H:i:sO` right?
But, in the database I have the format is `Y-m-d H:i:s.uO`, I don't actually know why that format, but it isn't my database and I have to work with it.
So how I can change the format of the field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own types.

Symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types
Doctrine: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types

The transformation is then performed in the methods called `convertToPHPValue` and `convertToDatabaseValue`.